# Conda / apt-get & issues installing graph-tool

Tags: apt, package-management, python, anaconda

I'm a bit confused about the different package managers on python / Ubuntu. I've recently immigrated to Ubuntu from windows, in which I used anaconda as my python package manager.

I've installed anaconda on my new Ubuntu setup. I want to use [graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/download), so I've followed the instructions on the webpage, and installed the precompiled packages using apt-get, which luckily (hopefully?) installed all dependencies.

The package appears to be installed in the Ubuntu system (`apt search graph-tool` indicate it as installed) while it does not appear in the conda packages list (`conda list`).

I've also tried to download this package from [anaconda.org](http://anaconda.org), but it didn't installed all dependencies, and installation failed:

```
$ conda install -c floriangeigl -c vgauthier -c msarahan -c bioconda -c ostrokach -c salford_systems -c ptorrestr -c pkgw -c kalefranz graph-tool
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eli/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 479, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/eli/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 145, in _main
    exit_code = args.func(args, p)
  File "/home/eli/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 80, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'install')
  File "/home/eli/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 420, in install
    raise CondaRuntimeError('RuntimeError: %s' % e)
CondaRuntimeError: Runtime error: RuntimeError: Runtime error: HTTPError: 404 Client Error: NOT FOUND for url: https://conda.anaconda.org/ostrokach/linux-64/libgcc-5-5.4.0-2.tar.bz2: https://conda.anaconda.org/ostrokach/linux-64/libgcc-5-5.4.0-2.tar.bz2
```

My understanding is that the graph-tool package is installed on Ubuntu, but not "exposed" to conda (am I correct?). How do I expose / add it to conda (and all its dependencies)? In general, what is the relation between packages exposed via apt-get and conda? How should I integrate packages installed via apt-get in conda?

Can you please explain the relations between the different package managers (should I use anaconda at all?) ?

Comment: is it possible to install Conda with apt-get or some official package manager for ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

In general there should be little to no interaction between conda-installed and apt-installed packages. At least that's the intention, although there are a lot of ways you can get yourself into trouble.

I'm not familiar with graph-tool, except for just-now looking at the website.  It's got quite the list of dependencies.  I also looked on anaconda.org for it, and found the gnarly conda install incantation with all of those channels--the one that caused you problems. (One of those channels is mine.)

One piece of advice is to be mindful of what you're actually interacting with on `PATH`. Executing `echo $PATH` will show you the contents of that environment variable, and the directories along with their order is key. To help you figure out what's being recognized as an executable, use `which -a`. For example, `which -a python`.

With all of those dependencies, I'm not surprised you're having problems. My second piece of advice is to try using a conda env. A conda env will help isolate all of your dependencies.

Try the command

```
conda create --name graphtool -c floriangeigl -c vgauthier -c msarahan -c bioconda -c ostrokach -c salford_systems -c ptorrestr -c pkgw -c kalefranz graph-tool
```

where the `--name graphtool` creates a new env named graphtool. Then run

```
source activate graphtool
```

to activate the env. From there, you should be able to execute (in the same terminal session) whatever graph-tool commands you need.

Now to the stack trace you got when you tried your `conda install` command...

It appears there's an issue with anaconda.org and the libgcc-5 package on the ostrokach channel. The stack trace indicates you got a 404 NOT FOUND error for the URL

```
https://conda.anaconda.org/ostrokach/linux-64/libgcc-5-5.4.0-2.tar.bz2
```

that anaconda.org indicated existed in https://conda.anaconda.org/ostrokach/linux-64/repodata.json. If this particular error persists, file an issue (maybe even referencing this thread) at https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/support/issues.

Comment: Thank you, this was quite detailed and helpful. I have opened an issue in github. However, I have two more questions:

Comment: I had listed the questions in another [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/854317/questions-about-conda-environments) in order to make it self-contained. Please let me know if you have any advice on those matters.

Comment: is it possible to install Conda with apt-get or some official package manager for ubuntu?

Comment: We haven't yet built deb or rpm installers.  It's on our radar and something we really want to get to someday soon.